# Где ошибка в коде Javascript

Tags: javascript

```js
function soundClick() {
    var audio = new Audio(); // Создаём новый элемент Audio
    audio.src = "1.mp3"; // Указываем путь к звуку "клика"
    audio.autoplay = true; // Автоматически запускаем
}
    
setInterval(function() {
    var hash = "5654654666";
    $.ajax({
        url:"live2.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            "hash": hash,
        },
        success: function(res1){
            r = JSON.parse(res1);
            if(r.status == "none"){
                $("#modal_wait").css({
                    "display": "none"
                });
            }else if(r.status == "succ"){ 
                soundClick();
            }
        },  
        error: function(){},
    });
}, 2000);
```

soundClick(); не запускает

Comment: Это так и должно быть? "hash": hash,

Comment: И запятая должна быть? error: function(){

},

Comment: @Arcadiy а  что не так с  "hash": hash? и что не так с запятой?

Comment: `soundClick(); не запускает` с чего Вы это взяли?